# cannot use test on variable to exit in citrus repeat until statement

Tags: integration-testing, citrus-framework

Using citrus I'm trying to repeat some actions within a "repeat until" container and cannot find a way to use another variable than the loop index.

Here is the basic form that works

> ```
>       repeat().until("i = 5")
>         .actions(
>             sleep(2000L),
>             applyBehavior(new GetProcessState())
>         );
> ```

See below some attempts to add some other conditions.

I tried this:

> ```
>     repeat().until("(i = 5) and @assertThat(${processState},equalTo('RUNNING'))@)").index("i")
> ```

and this

> ```
>     repeat().until("(i = 5) and (${processIsRunning}=false)").index("i")
> ```

But could not get it work. Anyone has an idea how to achieve this ?

Thx beforehand for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second approach is actually correct. Unfortunately, due to some implementation detail, one has to add surrounding spaces to groups containing boolean strings.
Otherwise Citrus will fail to parse the expression correctly.

E.g.

```
repeat().until("(i = 5) and ( ${processIsRunning} = false )").index("i")
```

Comment: @ s1h Thx a lot for your answer. I kind of put on hold my Citrus work, will get back to it & confirm whether it fixed my pb.

Comment: For the record: This [PR](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/pull/598) just got merged, so with version 2.7.10 and above, Citrus will parse the given expression without additional spaces correctly.